# Why do mathematicians use notation such as $i,j$ or $n, m$ or $\mu, \nu$, etc?

Tags: soft-question, notation

Many math textbooks and papers often introduce certain variables that are different, but the symbols chosen to represent these variables are often very *similar*.

For example, if one variable is denoted by $i$, the other will be $j$, instead of anything else, like $a, b,$ or $c$.

Likewise, if one variable is called $\mu$, the other will of course be called $\nu$.

Also, there is the $m, n$-pair from algebra books, which could get mixed up by some people. We could easily have defined matrices as having $r$ rows and $c$ columns, but why did mathematicians decide on $m$ and $n$?

Why have mathematicians chosen this style of notation?

Comment: one word; "convention"

Comment: Might I ask what answer you're expecting here? Are you expecting some first-order logic derivation that this is, in some secret and special way, the most efficient way of doing things? Is there a question here or are you just annoyed?

Comment: And matrices in german would have $z$ rows and $s$ columns, in french $l$ rows and $c$ columns – and in chinese?

Comment: If $\mu$ is a measure, perhaps the similarity of the letter $\nu$ with the letter $\mu$ helps remind the reader that $\nu$ is also a measure. The letters $i$ and $j$ are often used as indexes, and adhering to conventions like that arguably helps the reader understand notation more quickly. Your idea about using $r$ and $c$ for the number of rows and columns of a matrix does not seem bad to me, but perhaps $r$ needs to be used for "rank", and also the names $m$ and $n$ remind us they are integers. Good math authors try hard to find clear notation, but you might be able to do better sometimes.

Comment: What would you have in its place?

Comment: This question would fit better on opthalmology.stackexchange, if only it existed.

Comment: Have you considered getting screened for dyslexia/dysgraphia? Also, and I don’t mean this offensively, but “I personally suspect that it is a second attempt at scaring the laypeople away for maths and protecting the secrets” as a ring a paranoia psychosis to it, so I highly doubt that’s the reason. Perhaps take that up with the Illuminati?

Comment: The OP would probably approve of Jordan's notation. See the quote from Littlewood's Miscellany:
http://karthikey.blogspot.com/2005/10/jordans-direct-notation.html

Comment: Why does the English language use the symbols $a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z$?  After all, p, kind of looks like a reflected q, and u can easily be mistakened by v.  And: Why do we use `$` to denote "dollar"? Why do we use $(\cdot), [ \cdot], \{\cdot\}$ to denote brackets?  Why do  we ....

Answer (score 8):

Possibly too opinion-based, but I'll try to offer an answer.

Mathematicians often try to use similar letters for the same objects. So if you see the letters $\mu$ or $\nu$ in a measure theory textbook, chances are they will refer to measures. If you see $i$ or $j$, it will probably refer to integers. If you see $x,y,z$, it will more probably be real numbers, $z$ will be a complex number, and $f,g,h$ will be functions. Obviously, these are tendencies and not absolute rules.

Sure, you could name your measures $\mu$ and $x$, but would it really make it easier to read?

Comment: It's also really helpful to group similar objects by similar symbols --- for example, you can have two general complex numbers $a + bi$ and $m + ni$, and having consecutive letters can be a helpful reminder of which letters belong to which complex number in calculations.